# EditText Android, [new to android]

Tags: android, android-edittext

What I plan to make is, make an empty EditText and when the Players or Users Typed my answer word/numbers it will automatically say "Correct" and it will not react to anything else,
it is named "test" because, once I get it working I'm gonna use the code for the little guessing game I'm gonna create :)

here is the java.

```
package com.example.test;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity  {
    EditText who;
    String name = "";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 
        name = who.getText().toString();
        if(name.matches("rumia"));   
        Toast.makeText(this, "Correct", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

here's the XML

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:background="@android:color/black">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/who"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:ems="10"
        android:background="@android:color/white"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I tried various thing to make it to work (e.g. Just plain XML without designs(backgrounds/images))but can't get it to work.. still saying Unfortunately test has stopped..

Here's the Logcat

```
09-28 00:18:42.106: E/AndroidRuntime(3250): Process: com.example.test, PID: 3250
09-28 00:18:42.106: E/AndroidRuntime(3250): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.test/com.example.test.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-28 00:18:42.106: E/AndroidRuntime(3250):     at com.example.test.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:20)
09-28 00:18:50.806: E/WindowManager(372): Starting window AppWindowToken{b523b308 token=Token{b4f45670 ActivityRecord{b4f7af58 u0 com.example.test/.MainActivity t4}}} timed out
09-28 00:20:10.586: E/AndroidRuntime(3311): Process: com.example.test, PID: 3311
09-28 00:20:10.586: E/AndroidRuntime(3311): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.test/com.example.test.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-28 00:20:10.586: E/AndroidRuntime(3311):     at com.example.test.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:23)
09-28 00:20:19.296: E/WindowManager(372): Starting window AppWindowToken{b525be10 token=Token{b5006af8 ActivityRecord{b5016630 u0 com.example.test/.MainActivity t5}}} timed out
09-28 00:24:07.836: E/AndroidRuntime(3361): Process: com.example.test, PID: 3361
09-28 00:24:07.836: E/AndroidRuntime(3361): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.test/com.example.test.MainActivity}:  java.lang.NullPointerException
09-28 00:24:07.836: E/AndroidRuntime(3361):     at com.example.test.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:21)
09-28 00:24:16.826: E/WindowManager(372): Starting window AppWindowToken{b526fe78 token=Token{b4f9d330 ActivityRecord{b4d98c78 u0 com.example.test/.MainActivity t6}}} timed out
09-28 00:28:19.376: E/AndroidRuntime(3407): Process: com.example.test, PID: 3407
09-28 00:28:19.376: E/AndroidRuntime(3407): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.test/com.example.test.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-28 00:28:19.376: E/AndroidRuntime(3407):     at com.example.test.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:17)
09-28 00:28:27.876: E/WindowManager(372): Starting window AppWindowToken{b5250f38 token=Token{b4e1ed28 ActivityRecord{b4ff97f8 u0 com.example.test/.MainActivity t7}}} timed out
09-28 00:31:57.366: E/AndroidRuntime(3454): Process: com.example.test, PID: 3454
09-28 00:31:57.366: E/AndroidRuntime(3454): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.test/com.example.test.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-28 00:31:57.366: E/AndroidRuntime(3454):     at com.example.test.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:17)
09-28 00:32:06.026: E/WindowManager(372): Starting window AppWindowToken{b5276900 token=Token{b5225168 ActivityRecord{b4f8f4a8 u0 com.example.test/.MainActivity t8}}} timed out
09-28 00:33:25.616: E/AndroidRuntime(3500): Process: com.example.test, PID: 3500
09-28 00:33:25.616: E/AndroidRuntime(3500): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.test/com.example.test.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-28 00:33:25.616: E/AndroidRuntime(3500):     at com.example.test.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:17)
09-28 00:33:34.496: E/WindowManager(372): Starting window AppWindowToken{b5257c88 token=Token{b52659a0 ActivityRecord{b4ff97f8 u0 com.example.test/.MainActivity t9}}} timed out
09-28 00:36:09.836: E/AndroidRuntime(3547): Process: com.example.test, PID: 3547
09-28 00:36:09.836: E/AndroidRuntime(3547): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.test/com.example.test.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-28 00:36:09.836: E/AndroidRuntime(3547):     at com.example.test.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:17)
09-28 00:36:18.316: E/WindowManager(372): Starting window AppWindowToken{b525c520 token=Token{b5244b60 ActivityRecord{b5016630 u0 com.example.test/.MainActivity t10}}} timed out
09-28 00:42:10.286: E/AndroidRuntime(3583): Process: com.example.test, PID: 3583
09-28 00:42:10.286: E/AndroidRuntime(3583): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.test/com.example.test.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-28 00:42:10.286: E/AndroidRuntime(3583):     at com.example.test.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:17)
09-28 00:44:05.186: E/AndroidRuntime(3629): Process: com.example.test, PID: 3629
09-28 00:44:05.186: E/AndroidRuntime(3629): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.test/com.example.test.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-28 00:44:05.186: E/AndroidRuntime(3629):     at com.example.test.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:17)
09-28 00:44:13.996: E/WindowManager(372): Starting window AppWindowToken{b522efa0 token=Token{b51cc708 ActivityRecord{b5104bb8 u0 com.example.test/.MainActivity t12}}} timed out
09-28 00:44:56.576: E/AndroidRuntime(3676): Process: com.example.test, PID: 3676
09-28 00:44:56.576: E/AndroidRuntime(3676): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.test/com.example.test.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-28 00:44:56.576: E/AndroidRuntime(3676):     at com.example.test.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:17)
09-28 00:45:05.136: E/WindowManager(372): Starting window AppWindowToken{b51c3570 token=Token{b4ff9098 ActivityRecord{b4ff88a0 u0 com.example.test/.MainActivity t13}}} timed out
09-28 00:49:34.606: E/AndroidRuntime(3722): Process: com.example.test, PID: 3722
09-28 00:49:34.606: E/AndroidRuntime(3722): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.test/com.example.test.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-28 00:49:34.606: E/AndroidRuntime(3722):     at com.example.test.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:17)
09-28 00:49:43.276: E/WindowManager(372): Starting window AppWindowToken{b5257c88 token=Token{b51dda88 ActivityRecord{b502c6c0 u0 com.example.test/.MainActivity t14}}} timed out
09-28 00:52:00.506: E/AndroidRuntime(3770): Process: com.example.test, PID: 3770
09-28 00:52:00.506: E/AndroidRuntime(3770): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.test/com.example.test.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-28 00:52:00.506: E/AndroidRuntime(3770):     at com.example.test.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:17)
09-28 00:52:09.396: E/WindowManager(372): Starting window AppWindowToken{b5270b48 token=Token{b4e77b28 ActivityRecord{b4ff88a0 u0 com.example.test/.MainActivity t15}}} timed out
09-28 00:53:46.216: E/AndroidRuntime(3817): Process: com.example.test, PID: 3817
09-28 00:53:46.216: E/AndroidRuntime(3817): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.test/com.example.test.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-28 00:53:46.216: E/AndroidRuntime(3817):     at com.example.test.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:17)
09-28 00:53:55.206: E/WindowManager(372): Starting window AppWindowToken{b52681d8        token=Token{b4f93ed0 ActivityRecord{b5029f80 u0 com.example.test/.MainActivity t16}}} timed out
09-28 00:55:21.036: E/AndroidRuntime(3865): Process: com.example.test, PID: 3865
09-28 00:55:21.036: E/AndroidRuntime(3865): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity  ComponentInfo{com.example.test/com.example.test.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-28 00:55:21.036: E/AndroidRuntime(3865):     at com.example.test.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:17)
09-28 00:55:30.136: E/WindowManager(372): Starting window AppWindowToken{b5257c88 token=Token{b4f72f20 ActivityRecord{b4ff88a0 u0 com.example.test/.MainActivity t17}}} timed out
```

Comment: Whats up with `if(name.matches("rumia")); ` thats an `if` statement with no braces... just closed by a semicolon..im surprised that compiles(?)

Comment: yes it does.. and no errors and warnings O.o I tried adding braces but still same

Comment: have a look at textwatcher in android..

Comment: I'll look for it thanks

Comment: Just want to say Thanks to those who helped.. all is working now.. now I just need to find out how the score changes will stay even when you close or pressed "back" on the app XD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    EditText who;
    String name = "";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 
        who = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.who);

        // Create some button for event then get value from Edit Text
        name = who.getText().toString();
        if(name.matches("rumia")) 
        Toast.makeText(this, "Correct", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: are you casting it, like - who = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.who);

Comment: Just want to say Thanks to those who helped.. all is working now.. now I just need to find out how the score changes will stay even when you close or pressed "back" on the app XD

Comment: use sharedPreferences.

Answer (score 0):

Before `name = who.getText().toString();`, you should add `who = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.who);`

Comment: Just want to say Thanks to those who helped.. all is working now.. now I just need to find out how the score changes will stay even when you close or pressed "back" on the app XD